# How to bring back normal insert key behavior to Word 2007/10?

Tags: microsoft-word

Traditionally insert is used to switch between insert and overtype mode. In Word 2007 and 2010 it does nothing for me and I must use mouse to switch modes. How do I bring back the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1):

Office 2010:

1. Open **Options** from the **File** menu.
2. Select **Advance** from the left hand menu.
3. Check the **Use the Insert key to control overtype mode** option.
4. Click **OK**